# php equivalent to C's fputc

Tags: php, c, fopen, fwrite

I am wondering if there is an equivalent to C's fputc in PHP?
I am trying to do the following C code in PHP:

```
fputc(0x10, fp);
```

more information on fputc: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output#Writing_to_a_stream_using_fputc

Thanks

Comment: [fputs](http://php.net/fputs) with a string with just 1 byte?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the character code directly to the file:

```
fputs($fp, "\x10");
// or
fputs($fp, chr(16)); 
// or
fputs($fp, chr(hexdec(10));
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not treat single characters as a special type. Buts, as  PHP [string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) is just an sequence of octects, there is no problem in writing this:

```
  fwrite(fp,"\x10");
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to open a file in binary mode and then use

- use the [function pack](https://www.php.net/pack) to pack the int in the type of int you want
- then use the [function fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) on the value you packed